# SQL server updating a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update a table from another one. There are 200 columns so can't do  `set tabA.colA = tabB.colA` for all the columns. Is there another solution for that?

Comment: Simply hard work typing a lot.

Comment: Just use excel to generate all mappings :)

Comment: *There are 200 columns so can't do...* well you can, you just don't want to

Comment: @AlexanderVolok what i did thanks!

Comment: @ta.speot.is yes i have to do it for many files aggregating to 1000+ columns so no i can't do it without spending the day on it :) so i followed alexander volok: Created a spreadsheet in excel,  a cell for tabA name a cell for tabB name  and a column with all the column names and i did a simple formula in excel that did it in 3 seconds instead of 2 hours and adaptable to any table . plus PSK gave a dynamic query i didn't test it but that's a pretty smart way to handle this issue in the long run :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no shortcut for this except building a dynamic query.

If the column name are same in both the tables you can try like following.

```
DECLARE @UpdateStatement VARCHAR(max)

SET @UpdateStatement = 'UPDATE Destination SET ' + CHAR(10)

SELECT @UpdateStatement = @UpdateStatement + 'Destination.' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = Source.' + COLUMN_NAME + ', ' + CHAR(10)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'Destination'
-- append the TABLE NAME and WHERE condition to @UpdateStatement 
PRINT @UpdateStatement
```

You can add whatever condition you want to add in your  @UpdateStatement

Answer (score 0):

Simply write out the `UPDATE` statement and SET all the columns you need to change.

It's a bit of initial work.
But as long you're not regulary adding/removing columns, the SQL can be re-used.

```
UPDATE t
SET 
  colA = b.colA
, colB = b.bolB
-- add more columns here
FROM tableA t
JOIN tableB t2 ON -- <<the fields that the tables can be joined on>>
```

**Example snippet:**

```
-- using table variables for demonstration purposes
declare @tableA table (id int primary key identity(1,1), colA varchar(30), colB varchar(30), colC varchar(30));

declare @tableB table (id int primary key identity(1,1), tableAId int, colA varchar(30), colB varchar(30), colC varchar(30));

insert into @tableA (colA, colB, colC) values ('A1','A2','A3'),('A4','A5','A6');

insert into @tableB (tableAId, colA, colB, colC) values (1, 'B1','B2','B3'),(2, 'B4','B5','B6');

update t
set 
colA = t2.colA,
colB = t2.colB,
colC = t2.colC
from @tableA t
join @tableB t2 on t2.tableAId = t.id;

select * 
from @tableA;
```